# List to expression

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to take a list {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} and turn it into the following expression:

```
w^a+x^b+y^c*z+z^d "with weights:" {e,f,g,h}
```

Note that in the expression w,x,y and z will remain those variables.

Example:

```
{2,4,7,3,5,3,4,2}
```

would become:

```
w^2+x^4+y^7*z+z^3 "with weights:" {5,3,4,2}
```

But I don't need the quotation marks around with weights.

Comment: Take a look at `StringTemplate` and friends.

Comment: Perfect! Now where I put the numbers in for StringTemplate, they go in as elements separated by commas, and not as a list. How do I take a list, and remove the curly brackets?

Comment: do you mean `(y^c) *z` or `y^(c*z)`?

Comment: It is (y^c)*z. I know it seems like a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst2expr[x_List, vars_List] := With[{
   tmp = StringTemplate["`` with weights: ``"],
   powers = Take[x, Length[vars]],
   wts = Drop[x, Length[vars]]
   },
  tmp[ToString@InputForm[vars^powers], wts]
  ]
```

Try it out:

```
lst2expr[{2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2}, {w, x, y, z}]
```

**Edit:**

The solution above assumes you have a typo in the expression.  If not, you can use the following, which is less general but matches your suggested output.

```
lst2expr02[x_List] := With[{
   tmp = StringTemplate["w^``+x^``+y^``*z+z^`` with weights: ``"],
   powers = Take[x, 4],
   wts = Drop[x, 4]},
  tmp[Sequence @@ powers, wts]
  ]
```

Try it out:

```
lst2expr02[{2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2}]
```

Comment: either OP has made the same typo in 2 different spots  or your code produce a result different from what OP asked: take a look at the third term

Comment: @Alucard Yes.  I'm assuming a typo propagated by copy and paste.  But perhaps its not.

Comment: I know it appears to be, but it's not a typo

Comment: @KennethEaves Then see the edit.